# Retrieving data from grid view cell to a text box

Tags: c#, gridview, selectedindexchanged

I am trying to retrieve a cell data to a textbox , that will happen when i select any row in the grid view , the textbox will take the new value

I already enabled `auto post back` to the textbox

here is my code

```
protected void GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    TextBox3.Text = GridView2.Rows[GridView2.SelectedIndex].Cells[2].Text;
}
```

however , there is not error in the syntax , it doesn't retrieve any thing in the textbox , any suggestions ?

i am using

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;
```

I work in C# , Visual studio 2010 express web developer

Comment: What does the cell look like in the XML side? Is it a templatefield or a boundfield?

Comment: @Bader: If you have the code behind it stands to reason you also have the front side code.

Comment: <asp:BoundField DataField="cp_webspace" HeaderText="cp_webspace" 
                                SortExpression="cp_webspace" /> , i think its a boundField

Comment: @Bader: Then it really should be coming out as text. Are you sure it's the 3rd column?

Answer (score 3):

From VS 2010 documentation, I would recommend checking if the row and Cells are not null first.

```
// Get the currently selected row using the SelectedRow property.
GridViewRow row = CustomersGridView.SelectedRow;

// Display the company name from the selected row.
// In this example, the third column (index 2) contains
// the company name.
MessageLabel.Text = "You selected " + row.Cells[2].Text + ".";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel1.Visible = true;

    if (GridView2.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        webspace.Text = GridView2.Rows[GridView2.SelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text;
        Bandwidth.Text = GridView2.Rows[GridView2.SelectedIndex].Cells[2].Text;
        Email.Text = GridView2.Rows[GridView2.SelectedIndex].Cells[3].Text;
        FTP.Text = GridView2.Rows[GridView2.SelectedIndex].Cells[4].Text;
        Subdomain.Text = GridView2.Rows[GridView2.SelectedIndex].Cells[5].Text;
        mysql.Text = GridView2.Rows[GridView2.SelectedIndex].Cells[6].Text;

    }
```

that what i did in the event section, because i am sure it will be one row inside the grid view , so `if (GridView2.SelectedIndex == 0)`

thank you :)